# Trouble updating data on page from Firebase with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

```
  //Display User in header
  usersRef.child(uid).on('value', function(name){
    var dName = (name.val().displayName);
    $("#userName").replaceWith("<li id=userName><span>Logged in as " + dName + "</span></li>");
    //Get the first Letter of the users name
    firstLetter = dName.charAt(0);
    //Display icon in header
      console.log("User Image Replaced");
      $("#userImage").replaceWith("<li id='userImage'>" + firstLetter + "</li>");
  });
```

The above code successfully creates a user icon in the header of my website.  It is the first letter of their name with a background the color of their 'user color'.  When their 'user color' gets changed I want the icon in the header to update.

I have been getting mixed results, but usually it would update the first time I change the color and I would have to click around the page for it to do it again.  But not always, sometimes it would not work the first time and sometimes it would work the first three times.

Have I coded it in a way which is causing this problem or is it a Firebase thing?

Comment: You are replacing the element `#userName` each time there is an update. Therefore, it won't exist the next time the function is called. Try something like $('#username').html(...) instead?

Comment: I have been using replaceWith so it would replace the html with the updated html rather than have it repeated when it is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `child_changed` event for the firebase reference URL.

Following is the example:

```
usersRef.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {    
      document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = udata.name;
      document.getElementById("username").style.backgroundColor=udata.color;
});
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/learningloop/ha5wncmx/19/

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation.  While I am still having problems then it is helpful to see how it can be done when removed from my code.  FYI I think my problem is related to the classes not being removed correctly (each color is a class).